# GAPI Browser share

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is there a way to find the browser share for a site using Google analytics with GAPI? I see it can be done for each visit individually, but is there a way to get the share for each browser. I know Google collects the stat, as it can be accessed from their web dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

The core reporting api has [browser as one of the dimensions/metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets/platform#ga:browser) . Using this you can retrieve the visits for different browsers for your chosen date range. You can test this using [google analytics query explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/) . As shown in the image you can see the visits for each browser.

[image]

But i think for knowing percentage you need to calculate using these values.